# How do I create a JavaFX 8 ComboBox which can bind to a field on a seperate POJO

Tags: combobox, lambda, java-8, javafx-8

I have had a challenge finding anything on the following situation.  Let's say I have a record called DatabaseRecord which is a POJO with several fields:

```
public class DatabaseRecord {
    private Long recordId;
    private StringProperty foreignKeyId;
    private StringProperty otherValuesForMainRecord....

    ... setters/getters

public class LookUpDataValue {
    private String recordId;
    private String descriptiveText;
    private String otherValues.....
....
```

I have a combo box which displays the selectable values for the foreignKeyId value something like this:

```
@FXML
ComboBox<LookUpDataValue> combobox;

combobox.setCellFactory
    (new Callback<ListView<LookUpDataValue>, ListCell<LookUpDataValue>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<LookUpDataValue> call(ListView<LookUpDataValue> p) {
            ListCell<LookUpDataValue> cell = new ListCell<LookUpDataValue>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(LookUpDataValue item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText("");
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getDescriptiveText());
                    }
                }

            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

I would like to Bidirectionally bind the POJO DatabaseRecord.foreignKeyIdProperty to the combobox.valueProperty() - but this doesn't work since one is a string and one is a LookUpDataValue object.

I would like this combobox to be set correctly when the records are loaded, and conversely update the record when it's changed.

I would appreciate any pointers on where I can find an example of this...

Comment: The usual way to model the data here would be to have `DatabaseRecord` have a field of type `LookupDataValue` (or `ObjectProperty<LookupDataValue>` in the JavaFX world), instead of storing the foreign key. (The foreign key is essentially an implementation detail of how the data is stored, rather than a feature of the data itself.) Then have your database access code populate the field when loading from the database (or just use an ORM framework, which will manage this automatically). If you design the OO model that way, the binding is trivial. Do you have the opportunity to refactor like that?

Comment: I'm not sure at this point. My legacy system is pretty old. Some of the dtos are formulated that way, others not so much.  I'll take a look and see if that would work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to change my datamodel so I found the following solution which works.

```
// Handle ComboBox event.
myComboBox.setOnAction((event) -> {
    LookUpDataValue selected = myComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if(selected != null){
        dto.setForeignKeyId(selected.getId());
    }
});
```

This works well.  Thanks for your comments.